# Private key, access Gitolite repository for Netbeans on Win XP

Tags: git, netbeans, windows-xp, public-key, gitolite

Where to put private key to have access to Gitolite repository form Netbeans 7 ?

I have created a Public/Private key pair and did all the Gitolite configurations as described [here](http://sitaramc.github.com/gitolite/doc/2-admin.html#_adding_users_and_repos). However I don't know where to put the keys in order to clone the repository from the server using Netbeans 7 (using Git plugin version 0.2.11.42, which is able to clone the repository directly from Netbeans) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it should be in your home directory of the user you are running as.

```
~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

Comment: So Git plugin from Netbeans will look in that folder for id_rsa ? I done so and I have putted there the private key, but when I try to Clone the repository, it display the message: `git@myhost.com:myrepository: reject HostKey: myhost.com`

Comment: It would be under what id netbeans runs under

Comment: Yes but it seams that Netbeans is not reaching this folder. Because I have checked with the private key in that folder and then I deleted and the error message remain the same. Do I need to do some settings in Netbeans?

Comment: Same here, at least in OSX, netbeans dont reach id_rsa.